# After using pyinstaller my program freezes when running subprocess.run() command

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, pyinstaller

I am building my Python tool with pyinstaller. When I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile start.py
```

My generated start.exe works fine and all functionalities work, but when I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole start.py
```

My tool will just freeze on this code:

```
output = subprocess.run(["arp", "-a"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

I have more things like this for netstat and ipconfig etc. I can't find why it works when a console is open, but it doesn't work when the console is closed. Can someone please explain to me why this is and maybe an example on how it should be. I am pretty new to Python and Pyinstaller.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

The "arp -a" command is now working after making my Python code into .exe, but when it gets to:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["systeminfo"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

shell=True doesn't matter. It doesn't work without and with it.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have trief a lot ,but it won't work after I use pyinstaller with --noconsole command.

Comment: Does  `output  = subprocess.getoutput("arp -a");` give the same error?

Comment: @PedroLobito unfortunately it doesn't work. It creates the file, but it still gets stuck at the subprocess line.

Comment: Try: `subprocess.Popen(["arp -a"])`, same error?

Comment: When I run the tool in Pycharm or the exe without --noconsole it works, but without it, it still won't write to my file.

Comment: @PedroLobito I have solved the question for arp -a, but when it tries to run the same code, but with systeminfo. Nothing happens again. I think it is very weird and shell=True also doesn't help here. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that when using the --noconsole parameter with pyinstaller you also need to include "stdin=" and "stdout=".

My problem was solved with this code:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["arp", "-a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.read().decode("utf=8"))
```

I hope this will help others that come across the same problem!

Thanks @PedroLobito for the help and finding a part of the answer!